# Pymongo document query for conversion to INI file

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, ini

```
{
"name":"food",
"core":{
    "group":{
        "carbs":{
            "USA":{
                "breakfast":"potatoes",
                "dinner":"pasta"
            },
            "europe":{
                "breakfast":"something",
                "dinner":"something"
            }
        },
        "dessert":{
                            "USA":{
                                    "breakfast":"potatoes",
                                    "dinner":"pasta"
                            },
                            "europe":{
                                    "breakfast":"something",
                                    "dinner":"something"
                            }
        },
        "veggies":{
                            "USA":{
                                    "breakfast":"potatoes",
                                    "dinner":"pasta"
                            },
                            "europe":{
                                    "breakfast":"something",
                                    "dinner":"something"
                            }
                     }  
              }
        }
 }
```

I am trying to find a way to just return the core groups (carbs, dessert, and veggies).

i have the following python code but it returns all the values in the document, when i am only interested in the core.group

```
data = collection.foodie.find({"name":"food"},{"name":False, '_id':False, "core.groups.carbs.europe":False, "core.groups.dessert.europe":False, "core.groups.veggies.europe":False
```

The end result is an INI file with the type of group as the section name for USA only like below, which is why I am looking for a way to just list the groups so i can dynamically look for the actual values stored for when I do not know the groups (have them hardcoded like core.group.dessert.europe)

```
[carbs]
breakfast=potatoes
dinner=pasta

[dessert]
breakfast=potatoes
dinner=pasta

[veggies]
breakfast=potatoes
dinner=pasta
```

Comment: Do you think that the subdocument as `core.groups.*` and not `core.group.*` in your `pymongo` query is resulting in the projection rule not taking effect?

Comment: What are you expecting the "database" to do here? The `.find()` method will not alter or "flatten" the structure of the document itself, and that operation is really best left to performing in your client code. Of course you can basically do `.find({ "name": "food" }, { "_id": 0, "core.group": 1 })` to only return the required nested structure. Whilst "possible" with latest versions to flatten in the "server" and even say just match the "USA" entries, the methods used are not really intended for this use case, and the python code to manipulate is much simpler than the server methods.